# html gets rendered differently in webview and desktop browser

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

The HTML content, when loaded in an android webview, gets rendered differently when compared to how it's rendered inside a desktop browser. The differences are marked with a red/green circle in the attached images.

Example 1:
[image: HTML loaded in webview]
[image: HTML loaded in google chrome(desktop)]
Example 2:
[image: HTML loaded in webview]
[image: HTML loaded in chrome(desktop)]

Comment: unfortunately, that's how `WebView` works. It is not a full-functional web browser.

Comment: @VladMatvienko so you are suggesting that it is not something related to the content and its how webview behaves?

Comment: yes. It is something similar to how different browsers render same CSS - you often have to specify different CSS for each browser. From this point WebView can be treated as a *different web browser*, which requires different CSS.